# How can I utilize StreamWriter to write to a csv file?

Tags: c#, string, csv, stringbuilder, streamwriter

So here's what I'm working with.  I'm trying to take an XML file, pull the info from the attributes, append them together, and write it to a CSV file.  I'm still relatively new to programming, and the other programmer is out of the office today, so I could really use some assistance.

My first question, regards the StringBuilder.  Do I need to have an AppendLine at the end of my StringBuilder, so that each string output from the foreach loop is on a new line?  And would I need to do that inside the foreach loop?

My second question regards actually writing my string to the CSV file.  Would it look something like?

```
swOutputFile.WriteLine(strAppendedJobData)
```

And I think this would also go inside the foreach loop, but I'm not too sure.

Thanks for the help, I hope I've worded my question in a somewhat easy to understand manner.

```
//Create a stream writer to write the data from returned XML job ticket to a new CSV
        StreamWriter swOutputFile;
        string strComma = ",";
        swOutputFile = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:\\Dev\\AppendedJobData.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read));

        //Get nodes from returned XML ticket
        XmlNodeList xmlJobs = xdResults.SelectNodes("/Updates/Jobs/Job");
        //Pull out data from XML attributes
        foreach (XmlElement xeJobUpdate in xmlJobs)
        {
            //Break down the job data
            string strProjectID = xeJobUpdate.GetAttribute("SharpOwlProjectID");
            string strJobNumber = xeJobUpdate.GetAttribute("JobNumber");
            string strClientCode = xeJobUpdate.GetAttribute("SharpOwlClientCode");
            string strClient = xeJobUpdate.GetAttribute("Client");
            string strVCAOffice = xeJobUpdate.GetAttribute("VCAOffice");
            string strLoadStatus = xeJobUpdate.GetAttribute("LoadStatus");

            //Build the string to be added to the new CSV file

            StringBuilder sbConcatJob = new StringBuilder();
            sbConcatJob.Append(strProjectID).Append(strComma).Append(strJobNumber)
                .Append(strComma).Append(strClientCode).Append(strComma).Append(strClient).Append(strComma)
                .Append(strVCAOffice).Append(strComma).Append(strLoadStatus).Append(strComma);
            string strAppendedJobData = sbConcatJob.ToString();
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? Also, what problem are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two options here:

If you call `sbConcatJob.AppendLine()` inside the foreach loop you can build the contents of the file in one string builder then call `swOutputFile.Write(sbConcatJob.ToString())` outside of the foreach loop to write the file.

If you keep your code as it is now you can add `sw.OutputFile.WriteLine(sbConcatJob.ToString())` inside the foreach loop and write the file one line at a time.

Answer (score 9):

if you want to do it a bit more elegant you could do something like that:

```
 using(StreamWriter swOutputFile = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("C:\\Dev\\AppendedJobData.csv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)))
    {
        //Get nodes from returned XML ticket
        XmlNodeList xmlJobs = xdResults.SelectNodes("/Updates/Jobs/Job");
        //Pull out data from XML attributes
        foreach (XmlElement xeJobUpdate in xmlJobs)
        {
           List<String> lineItems = new List<String>();
           lineItems.add(xeJobUpdate.GetAttribute("SharpOwlProjectID"));
           //add all the other items

           swOutputFile.WriteLine(String.Join(',', myLine.ToArray()));



        }
    //after the loop you close the writer
   }

    //all the work is done much easier
```

Comment: Just what I was thinking. One correction. List(T).Join is for merging lists, what you need to do is something like String.Join(',', myLine.ToArray())

Comment: StreamWriter is IDisposable so it should placed in a 'using' block so that `Close` is guaranteed to be called.

Comment: Thanks for the help, if I could accept more than one answer, I would have accepted yours as well, I went with Phil's answer because it was the one I used.

Answer (score 2):

> My first question, regards the
>   StringBuilder. Do I need to have an
>   AppendLine at the end of my
>   StringBuilder, so that each string
>   output from the foreach loop is on a
>   new line? And would I need to do that
>   inside the foreach loop?

My only advice since it appears you have not attempted this would be to try it.  It is the only way you will learn.

> swOutputFile.WriteLine(strAppendedJobData)

This would write an entire line of text to a file.